# Second scanf jump scan in GO

Tags: go, scanf

Dears,

I am writing some basic programs that need to receive more than one variable, following the formed

```
fmt.printf ("Report number")
fmt.scanf ("%f", &num1)
fmt.printf ("Report number")
fmt.scanf ("%f", &num2)
```

But the second scanf is always skipped, if I put a third, it is read normally.
How do I do it, so that all Scanfs are recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to end the read after hitting an enter, you want to add a new line into your format

```
fmt.printf ("Report number")
fmt.scanf ("%f\n", &num1)
fmt.printf ("Report number")
fmt.scanf ("%f\n", &num2)
```